# How To Withdraw From A Smart Contract

Tags: web3j, solidity-0.8.x

I have a smart contract with the below method:

```
    function send(address payable _to) public payable isOwner{
        
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
        emit Fallback(_to, data);
    }


    fallback() external payable {
         emit Fallback(msg.sender, msg.data);
    }
```

The contract doesn't have a withdraw function because I was told that when a fallback method exists, a function that isn't defined can be sent to the contract provided the sender has the right permissions.
In the web3j code I'm using, I put the function, recipient and the amount in the data and send then send a zero value; however, the code doesn't generate any transaction.

```
final BigInteger transferAmountWei = Convert.toWei("0.02998", Convert.Unit.ETHER).toBigIntegerExact();
            List<Type> params = Arrays.asList(new Address("0xCa807355403Fc1239a19e0Be15b0bed4Fcd7ED78"), new Address("0xe3402fFfC68ff431bDEcD54260C7A363E68c9F2F"),new Uint(transferAmountWei));

            String data = FunctionEncoder.encode(new Function("call", params, Collections.emptyList()));
```

That transaction can be viewed here: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8ed94913b2c116d26d32be176cd6a97b7ce30b69a51d5783e4f0b19bc3814d6e

Can you please assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The line "*when a fallback method exists, a function that isn't defined can be sent to the contract*" means when a function is not defined and you call it inside a contract then the fallback is called, but to execute the call correctly **you would need to add the logic inside the fallback function**. The fallback itself doesn't know what to do with the passed data it just executes with whatever logic you have provided inside the fallback function.

Comment: Thanks Zartaj for this answer. I guess the funds are locked in this smart contract then

Comment: yes, there's no way to recover those.